# SELECT COUNT FROM table FOR multiple data

Tags: mysql

I'm gonna try to explain my problem. I had a problem to figure how to named it so I hope you will get it from the description.

I have 1 table. There are 3 important columns, it is not important to bother with the other columns.
**Person who voted, Person who got the vote, and the rating**

I need to get 3 results (counts).

1) I need to have the count of all people who gave me rating 1 BUT I have not voted for them or I gave them rating 0.

2) The count of all people whem I gave rating 1 BUT they have not voted for me or they gave me rating 0.

3) The count of people that gave me rating  and I gave them also rating 1.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: tttpapi, for 3) is it that you both gave each other rating 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicities sake I'm assuming you don't need to do this in one query. If you do then you're just going to have to combine them as subqueries anyway. Conversely, to complicate matters slightly, I've assumed you might want to pull these stats for all users at once.

I've written these queries for the schema

```
Voter ( VoterID, Name )
Rating ( VoterID, VotedOnID, Rating )
```

I tested them on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/410af/69/0)

---

> 1) I need to have the count of all people who gave me rating 1 BUT I have not voted for them or I gave them rating 0.

```
SELECT v.Name, COUNT(s.VoterID) AS "They vote 1, you vote 0 or null"
FROM Voter v
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT a.VoterID, a.VotedOnID
  FROM Rating a 
  LEFT JOIN Rating b ON a.VotedOnID = b.VoterID 
                    AND b.VotedOnID = a.VoterID
  WHERE a.Rating = 1 
    AND (b.Rating IS NULL OR b.Rating = 0) 
) s ON v.VoterID = s.VotedOnID
GROUP BY v.VoterID, v.Name;
```

---

> 2) The count of all people whem I gave rating 1 BUT they have not voted for me or they gave me rating 0.

```
SELECT v.Name, COUNT(s.VoterID) AS "You vote 1, they vote 0 or null"
FROM Voter v
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT a.VoterID, a.VotedOnID
  FROM Rating a 
  LEFT JOIN Rating b ON a.VotedOnID = b.VoterID 
                    AND b.VotedOnID = a.VoterID
  WHERE a.Rating = 1 
    AND (b.Rating IS NULL OR b.Rating = 0) 
) s ON v.VoterID = s.VoterID
GROUP BY v.VoterID, v.Name;
```

**N.B.** This is exactly the same query as above except for the final `ON` condition.

---

> 3) The count of people that gave me rating **[of 1]** and I gave them also rating 1.

```
SELECT v.Name, COUNT(b.VotedOnID) AS "You both vote 1"
FROM Voter v
LEFT JOIN Rating a ON a.VoterID = v.VoterID 
                  AND a.Rating = 1
LEFT JOIN Rating b ON a.VotedOnID = b.VoterID 
                  AND b.VotedOnID = a.VoterID 
                  AND b.Rating = 1
GROUP BY v.Name;
```

Comment: I found a tiny problem here. I need to separate 1 and 2 from 3. I cannot have the same record in (1 OR 2) and in 3.
I tested the first one and it gave me also the result from 3 (when both give 1 to each other.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the answer with fixed queries and a new SQLFiddle

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT Count(Table1.Field), Count(Table2.Field), Count(Table3.Field) 
FROM Table1,Table2, Table3
```

Comment: that's far from the answer. Explain why?

Comment: even edited it has still the same effect, it does not help at all

Comment: The edit was just the formatting, think you can safely ignore this answer.

Comment: This has where clause missing. Once added i think would be the answer. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Not @IrfanShaikh,  all the elements are ready for a nice query.

Comment: Well, but this question is mostly about the where clause. It is obvious that I will need this construction. And even though I said I have 1 table.

Comment: That's sort of like someone asking how to build a car, you giving them 4 wheels and saying "now just add the car". And this is not even close to the right answer. OP clearly states he has one table, not 3.

Comment: On the bright-side you'll earn a nice shiny "peer-pressure" badge if you delete this.